# Reverse a list of items in sass using @for loop

Tags: css, math, sass

This is my @for loop in sass:

```
@for $i from 1 through 10 {
  #users[data-state='unload'] li:nth-child(#{$i}n) {
    animation-delay: #{$i * 0.1}s;
  }
}
```

Which generates this css:

```
#users[data-state=loaded] li:nth-child(1n) {
  animation-delay: 0.1s;
}

#users[data-state=loaded] li:nth-child(2n) {
  animation-delay: 0.2s;
}

#users[data-state=loaded] li:nth-child(3n) {
  animation-delay: 0.3s;
}
/// etc...
```

what i want to do is have my css read as:

```
#users[data-state=loaded] li:nth-child(1n) {
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

#users[data-state=loaded] li:nth-child(2n) {
  animation-delay: 0.9s;
}

#users[data-state=loaded] li:nth-child(3n) {
  animation-delay: 0.8s;
}
/// etc....
```

So I am wondering what is the math calculation needed to reverse the animation delay so that the last child element has the shortlist time and the first child element the longest?

many thanks
W9914420

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change animation-delay: **#{$i * 0.1}s**; as animation-delay: **#{(10 - $i) * 0.1}s**;

```
@for $i from 0 through 10 {
  #users[data-state='unload'] li:nth-child(#{$i}n) {
    animation-delay: #{(10 - $i) * 0.1}s;
  }
}
```